# Windows chkdsk command changes folder to text document

Tags: windows, chkdsk

Here's the story:

I have audio files on a separate, internal ntfs hard drive that I was working on using REAPER 5 (wine) on my Ubuntu 16.04 boot. I couldn't get the FX windows to work so I decided to switch to my Windows 10 boot on the same machine.

On Windows, the folder was there but when I tried to open it, the classic "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable." error appeared. I then ran `chkdsk /f d:` to fix the corrupted folder. Once the command was finished, I checked back and the folder had become a text file. Panicking, I switched back to Ubuntu only to find the folder was still a text file.

I attempted to find any .CHK files but none exist on the drive.

That folder had about 35 man hours worth of work in it and it would be devastating to start over. I know the data is not completely gone because that's not how hard drives work so I have two questions:

1) Can the link between the folder and files be re-established?

if not,

2) How can I manually recover the data from the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A Disk Editor could change the attribute of the pseudo-text file back to 'Directory'. This is worth an attempt, but you will have to get a disk editor and   give it sufficient privileges to do that.
2. Yes, any file recovery tool should be able to dig for the files that were in that Directory. There are [plenty of them listed here](https://www.lifewire.com/free-data-recovery-software-tools-2622893).